# Prove all the combinations in a matrix

Tags: r

, I'm working with a matrix (13x13) for svec model, I have an error ( ERROR : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.69571e-17) and this matrix only accept values 0 or NA , I have some restrictions:

```
SR[1:7 , 8:13]<-0
SR[1 , 1:6]<-NA
SR[,1]<-NA
SR[8:10 , 8:10]<-NA
SR[11:13 , 11:13]<-NA
```

so for the rest of the values (94) I need to prove all the possible combinations 94 in 1 , 94 in 2 , etc. to put 0 values. I want the code run until find matrix with not error.

I did this code, but only move 0 random values in the matrix, using tryCatch but that's the reason to prove the rest of the possible combinations.

```
mm<- matrix(0, 13,13)
   i<-0
   while (i< 500000) {
    SR<-apply(mm, c(1, 2), function(x) sample(c(0, NA), 1))
    SR[1:7 , 8:13]<-0
    SR[1 , 1:6]<-NA
    SR[,1]<-NA
    SR[8:10 , 8:10]<-NA
    SR[11:13 , 11:13]<-NA
    diag(SR)<-NA
    tryCatch({
      svec.b<- SVEC(vecm, LR = LR, SR = SR, r = 1, lrtest = FALSE, boot =     FALSE)},
    error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
    print(i)
    i=i+1
  }
```

(LR is another matrix, but that matrix is fixed)

I'll really appreciate all the help you can give me

Comment: What does "prove all possible combinations" mean?

Comment: On the rest of 94 values I need to move one 0 in all the possible values, next to prove each one of them. I mean the next is moving two 0 inside all the 94 values considering all the possible combinations. Next three zeros, four zeros,....., etc until the error doesn't appear.

Comment: What does "move a zero" mean? What does "prove a value" mean? Your contemporary impact matrix has zeros along the diagonal. This doesnt make sense.

Comment: For example, I  have a vector with 5 possible values (NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), the first step with one 0,  "move a zero " means, (0, NA, NA, NA, NA), (NA, 0 , NA , NA, NA) , (NA , NA, 0, NA, NA) , (NA , NA, NA, 0, NA) , and finally (NA, NA, NA, NA, 0) , considering all the possible combinations, next two zeros, etc. With "value" I'm talking about to the entries in the matrix. The diagonal in the matrix has values NA, it's one of the restrictions.

Comment: You seem not to understand how SVECs work. 1. You cant have zeros along the diagonal. A zero on the diagonal means that a shock to a variable doesnt affect its own value contemporaneously. 2. You have to have a justification for setting a contemporaneous impact coefficient to zero. That is what "structural" means in SVEC, You cant just try around untill it works

Comment: I don't have zeros in the diagonal, and actually is the reason to the restriction i'm defining , and I define matrix with the theorical restricctions but doesn't work , so I want to find a matrix and after that study the impact. For that reasson I want to prove all the combination to move the zeros in the restricctions.

Comment: If the restrictions you obtained from theory dont work you most likely dont have enough of them. But this is still not a reason to shop around for which to add. Theres no guarantee that the ones youll get by shoping around make any sense. Think about which restrictions can you add. The more make sense the better.